# Panel led 8x8 en Ensamblador

Tags: ensamblador

Tengo este codigo, estoy haciendo algunas practicas con ensamblador y proteus, el trabajo es hacer diferentes figuras en una matriz de leds, para posteriormente poder hacer un juego.

```
LIST P=PIC16F877A

INCLUDE<P16F877A.INC>
ORG 0



#DEFINE FILAS       PORTB
#DEFINE COLUMNAS    PORTC
#DEFINE ARRIBA      PORTA,0 
#DEFINE DERECHA     PORTA,1
#DEFINE ABAJO       PORTA,2
#DEFINE IZQUIERDA   PORTA,3
#DEFINE START       PORTA,4

M EQU 0X24
N EQU 0X25
O EQU 0X23
CONTA EQU 0X22

INICIO

    BSF STATUS,RP0
    CLRF FILAS
    CLRF COLUMNAS
    BCF ARRIBA
    BCF DERECHA
    BCF ABAJO
    BCF IZQUIERDA
    BCF START
    BCF STATUS,RP0
    MOVLW D'30'
    MOVWF CONTA



INICIO2
    CLRF FILAS
    CLRF COLUMNAS
    BTFSS PORTA,4
    GOTO INICIO2

    GOTO JUEGA

JUEGA
    MOVLW B'11111111'
    MOVWF FILAS
    MOVLW B'01111110'
    MOVWF COLUMNAS
    CALL DELAY

    MOVLW B'10000000'
    MOVWF PORTB
    MOVLW B'10001111'
    MOVWF PORTC
    CALL DELAY

    DECFSZ CONTA,1
    GOTO JUEGA
    GOTO JUEGA


DELAY
    MOVLW D'250' 
    MOVWF O
PRIMERO
    MOVLW D'1' 
    MOVWF M
SEGUNDO
    MOVLW D'250' 
    MOVWF N
TERCERO
    NOP
    NOP
    DECFSZ N,1
    GOTO TERCERO
    DECFSZ M,1
    GOTO SEGUNDO
    DECFSZ O,1
    GOTO PRIMERO

RETURN


END
```

El problema es que al hacer la simulacion en proteus con una matriz de 8x8, no logro hacer que se vean las dos cordenadas juntas, se ve una primero y despues la otra y lo que necesito es hacer que se vean juntas para por ejemplo poder formar una letra. Es decir, si quiero hacer la letra e, no me sale toda la letra completa,me van saliendo barra por barra, sale una, e borra, sale la otra, se borra y asi sucesivamente.

Comment: Voy a añadir en el comentario las cosas que recuerdo y/o se me ocurren: cuando uno sacaba a un 7 segmentos, había que usar un circuito que transformara la salida porque uno simplemente enviaba un binario que se interpretaba en la salida. E igual, uno siempre está pintando un led a la vez, sólo que aprovecha algún clock para pintar cada segmento por un instante.